# Asymptotic distribution of $n^r \frac{U_{(1)}}{U_{(n)}}$: figuring possible $r>0$

Tags: convergence, uniform-distribution, asymptotics, order-statistics

Consider the i.i.d. sample $U_1, U_2 \cdots, U_n$ from the uniform distribution $U(0, 1)$. I should find a possible values of $r>0$ to have an **asymptotic distribution** of
$$ n^r \frac{U_{(1)}}{U_{(n)}}$$

It is possible to get through with its CDF, and I know how to get it from the joint PDF of order statistics: the CDF of $U_{(1)}/U_{(n)}$ is obtained by

$$ F_{U_{(1)}/U_{(n)}} (x) = 1-(1-x)^{n-1}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  0<x<1 $$

However, what I indeed want it from here is the new approach. Because ths calculation of CDF is a bit tedious and tells nothing about the hidden meaning, I tried some different methods. It is proven that
$$ (nU_{(1)}, n(1-U_{(n)}))^T \overset{d}{\to} (Y_1, Y_2)^T$$
where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent standard exponential distribution, i.e., $Exp(1)$. Also for a continuous function $g$,
$$ X_n \overset{d}{\to} X \implies g(X_n)\overset{d}{\to} g(X) $$and hence tried to apply $g(x, y)=x/y$ but did not go well. Is this the right method ? Are there other elegant methods?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by a "possible $r$ to have an asymptotic distribution of $n^r \frac{U_{(1)}}{U_{(n)}}$."  I say that because the pdf of that random variable is $(n-1) n^{r-n r} \left(n^r-x\right)^{n-2}$ for $0\leq x \leq n^r$ and $n>1$ and $r>1$.

Comment: I changed some expressions, and was meaning that for some enough large $r$ the asymptotic distribution perhaps diverges as $n\to\infty$. So it was finding the possible range of $r $ to yield the convergent asymptotic distribution.

Comment: You have the cdf of $U_{(1)}/U_{(n)}$ wrong:  It is $1-(1-x)^{n-1}$ rather than $(1-x)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JimB Sorry that was my typo. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Since $U_{(n)}\stackrel{p}{\to}1$, $n^rU_{(1)}/U_{(n)}$ and $n^rU_{(1)}$ have the same limit.  So if you already know $nU_{(1)}$ has a non-degenerate limiting distribution, $nU_{(1)}/U_{(n)}$ has the same one.

It follows that $n^rU_{(1)}/U_{(n)}$ has the same limit as $n^{r-1}(nU_{(1)})$ for other $r$.  When $r<1$ convergence is to point mass at zero. When $r>1$ the sequence is not $O_p(1)$ and so does not converge in distribution.